# how to change/upgrade part of a Docker-image? a module inside the image, not the entire image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-image, apache-superset

first, is it theoritically correct & possible?
let's say: I have a Docker-image of Superset, composed of a few modules: Python, Postgres, Superset itself and etc.. the container runs fine, but I need to upgrade the Superset itself from v.1.15 to v.1.21 while the Python and other parts are satisfiyingly up-to-date.
How can I change/upgrade just the Superset part of the image?
(because the released image file hasn't updated it yet)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just "derive" from this image:

```
FROM amancevice/superset

RUN ...
```

From [docs.docker.com: run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from)
The FROM instruction initializes a new build stage and sets the Base Image for subsequent instructions.

---

When running with

```sh
docker build -t your_new_image .
```

you get a new image where `amancevice/superset` is as *base image*. The `RUN` command let you run any shell command you need t upgrade (see [docker.docs: run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run))

---

If you just want to upgrade inside a running container you can `exec` into it

```sh
docker exec -it <your container> bash
```

(or `sh`, whatever shell the container is using).

See [docs.docker.com: exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).
You can play around in your container but your changes are only applied to this container and does not affect new containers from this image.